# Protocols output in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript and again I have a question. As `document.write(location.protocol);` outputs the protocol used to send and receive data, something like http, https or something like that, but I'm placing a file on the desktop and opening it using the browser. So in the address bar it is showing me something like this:

> file:///C:/Users/malik/Desktop/display.html

```
//when i use 
document.write(location.protocol);
//it outputs 
//file:
```

I want to ask is ('file:') any protocol, if yes then which one?

Comment: You need to define `protocol`. If it is defined as TCP/IP protocol, then it isn't, but in respect to an URI scheme, it is, sort of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `file:` protocol isn't a real TCP/IP protocol, it's a virtual protocol used by browsers to specify a resource that is read from the local disk rather than over a TCP/IP connecction.

Ref: [List of TCP/IP protocols](http://www.protocols.com/pbook/tcpip1.htmI)

Different browsers may use the `file:` prefix in different ways.

[Internet Explorer implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The `file:` protocol refers to a file on your local machine.

Comment: so in this case there is file protocol is used?

Answer (score 1):

This part of url is officially called [scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax). Sometimes scheme reflects protocol (http), sometimes not (mailto, file, etc).